# How do I prevent every access of ip address but not with subfolder in apache

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

How do I prevent anyone who access my ip address but not with subfolder in apache.

Example:

44.555.666.777 <- I want to disable being access and instead I want to redirect it to another server which is in another domain.

44.555.666.777/v1 <-- They can access this!

How do I do this in which I have already my ProxyServer enabled.

I already have this, but this gives forbidden access I would want to is redirect them to page 404. In which is in another domain.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 44.555.666.777
    Allow from 127
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use mod_rewrite.  There are a few ways to achieve this with ModRewrite.  One would be along the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  "44.55.66.77"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/        - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)   "http://url.for.404.site/path" [R,L]
```

I've not tried it, so it will probably need some tweeking, but the idea is to  (1) Turn rewriting on, (2) match the destination IP rather then Virtual Host, (3) Ignore anything in a subdirectory and (4) rewrite anything else.

Comment: RewriteCond  [is this correct? ->"%{HTTP_HOST}  "44.55.66.77"

Comment: @david - Nope, the quote should not have been there.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please accept it.